# Keyboard repeating only working for characters, not other keys

Tags: keyboard, kubuntu, kde, keyboard-layout

I have an odd issue with my system where only character keys get repeated when pressed. The arrow keys, PGUP/PGDN, Numeric keypad, and BACKSPACE for example to not repeat. This makes navigating the system a pain as I have to press the affected keys repeatedly, say for example to delete some text in a line of code.

My KDE settings have Keyboard Repeat turned on, and I can't find out what's going on..

Keyboard is:
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 413c:2113 Dell Computer Corp. Dell KB216 Wired Keyboard

(and works fine on other computers)

Operating System: Kubuntu 20.04
KDE Plasma Version: 5.18.5
KDE Frameworks Version: 5.68.0
Qt Version: 5.12.8
Kernel Version: 5.4.0-65-generic
OS Type: 64-bit

Does anyone know what could be causing the issue?

Thanks

*edit* I don't believe it's a KDE issue, but I could be wrong.

*further edit* Output from im-config -a gives me
Current configuration for the input method:

- Active configuration: default (normally missing)
- Normal automatic choice: ibus (normally ibus or fcitx or uim)
- Override rule: zh_CN,fcitx:zh_TW,fcitx:zh_HK,fcitx:zh_SG,fcitx:ja_JP,fcitx:ko_KR,fcitx:vi_VN,fcitx
- Current override choice:  (en_IE)
- Current automatic choice: ibus
- Number of valid choices: 13 (normally 1)
  The override rule is defined in /etc/default/im-config.
  The configuration set by im-config is activated by re-starting X.
  Explicit selection is not required to enable the automatic configuration if the active one is default/auto/cjkv/missing.
  Available input methods: ibus fcitx fcitx5 uim hime gcin maliit scim hangul thai xim kinput2 xsunpinyin
  Unless you really need them all, please make sure to install only one input method tool.

Answer (score 0):

I rebooted into recovery console, ran fsck, rebooted and the issue had gone away. I don't understand why, so I cannot offer a good solution to the issue.